# Why does this code not brake out of the while Loop? issue with the absolute file path or name?

Tags: java, java-io

I'm trying to learn how to program and am not particularly good at the "external file" making Stuff (or much else). When I run the following code it never brakes out of the while loop. It works fine if I use an absolute path in makeFile() method i.e X = new Formatter("C:\Users\User Name\workspace\excrsice project 01\src\sample\t8.txt");. Can someone explain, why this happens? Plus, I don't think relying on Absolute paths is a great idea, so is there another way to do this or a better practice to follow?

```
static Stage window;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("EP1");
        //primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        this.window = primaryStage;
        window = t8.Run();
        window.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

```
public class task8 {


    Label label;
    Button B;
    VBox layout;
    Scene S;
    Stage M;

    public Stage Run(){

        label = new Label("this is the label");
        B = new Button("Press Me");
        B.setOnAction(e->{
            System.out.println("here");
            int counter = 0;
            while(counter <= 1){
                System.out.println("here 1");
                try{
                    File x = getFile();
                    if(x.exists()){
                        System.out.println("here 4");
                        label.setText("The File "+x.getName()+" has been engaged");
                        counter++;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("here 5");
                        makeFile();
                    }
                }catch(Exception a){
                    System.out.println(e);
                    label.setText("Mistakes were made in the Run");
                }
            }
        });
        layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label,B);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        S = new Scene(layout, 300,250);
        M = new Stage();
        M.setTitle("text file ex");
        M.setScene(S);
        return M;
    }

    public File getFile(){
        System.out.println("here 2");
        File X;
        try{
            System.out.println("here 3");
            X = new File("C:\\Users\\User Name\\workspace\\excrsice project 01\\src\\sample\\t8.txt");
        }catch(Exception e){
            X = null;
            System.out.println(e);
            label.setText("Mistakes were made in getFile");
        }
        return X;
    }

    public void  makeFile(){
        System.out.println("here 6");
        final Formatter X;
        try{
            System.out.println("here 7");

            X = new Formatter("t8.txt");
            label.setText("File Made");
        }catch(Exception e){
            label.setText("Mistakes were made in makeFile");
            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If x.exists() always returns false, then counter will never increment and the loop will never end.

The word "excrsice" is mispelled in the file path in getFile().

I recommend inventing variable names that describe what the variable is doing. For example, you have a variable named "counter". What is it counting? That should be obvious from the variable name.

Your loop seems to be designed to do just two passes because the exit condition is > 1 and the variable counter starts at 0. So, you have one pass at 0 and one pass at 1, then it exits. For doing only two things you should not use a loop, but should use if-statements and do the two things explicitly.

Comment: The word "excrsice" is misspelled everywhere, so it should really create an issue, lol (the actual file name is misspelled). This code still makes a file from the makeFile() method but does not break the loop afterward. Furthermore, it works fine if I change the make file path to an absolute path( i.e. -> Formatter X = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\User Name\\workspace\\excrsice project 01\\src\\sample\\t8.txt"); ). But I don't wanna relly on an absolute file path for this. is there another way to do this?

Comment: So, I kinda figured it out, the method "getFile()" with: X = new File("C:\\Users\\User Name\\workspace\\excrsice project 01\\src\\sample\\t8.txt"); and "makeFile()" with X = new Formatter("t8.txt"); refer to diffrent location, "getFile()" refers the "sample" folder and "makeFile()" refers to the "excrsice project 01" folder. Thanks for the suggestions tho. I would still love to know if there are any other ways to refer to a file path?